# Converting a string into a date Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm attempting to convert a string date into a date that can be stored in the database.  These are my attempts:

```
params[:event][:start_date] = '03-21-2016'
DateTime.strptime(params[:event][:start_date], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
```

or

```
DateTime.strptime(params[:event][:start_date], '%m-%d-%Y')
```

However I keep getting an invalid date error.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: When i try the latter, it works fine:  `DateTime.strptime('03-21-2016', '%m-%d-%Y') => Mon, 21 Mar 2016 00:00:00 +0000`

Comment: This works up to the 12th as the day but anything higher says argument out of range.  I'm assuming this is because the month and day are being switched but I don't understand how to fix that.

Comment: Presumably this is coming from a form in your website?  Maybe you have the day and month the wrong way round in that form?

Comment: If it is always coming through day then month just change the format string to `'%d-%m-%Y'`

Comment: Its required to be a certain format by the client.

Comment: It doesn't matter.  All that matters is that the form and the controller action agree on which format it is.  So either fix the form or fix the controller but just make it so that they both "agree" on the date format.  Do you know what i mean?

Comment: `"I'm assuming this is because the month and day are being switched but I don't understand how to fix that"`. Then spend more time reading [the `strftime` documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-strftime) which explains format strings. This is a very simple problem. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Comment: I've read the documentation and it still doesn't work.  Thanks for your non helping snide comment.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it would be this:

```
date_string = '03-21-2016'
month, day, year = date_string.split('-').map(&:to_i)
DateTime.new(year, month, day)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand what each fragment (eg `%Y`) in the format string (`'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'`) means: read this.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone/strftime

Once you know this, you can tailor a format string to the date string you have, or expect to get: in this case, `"%m-%d-%Y"`.

Comment: I've tried that format as well and get the same error.

Comment: Please add the value of `params[:event][:start_date]` to your question.  Check in your logs to see what it actually is, maybe it's not what you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

When debugging create a new, basic and simple, version of the code and test that.

```
require 'date'

params = '03-21-2016'
DateTime.strptime(params, '%m-%d-%Y') # => #<DateTime: 2016-03-21T00:00:00+00:00 ((2457469j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Note the order for the format: `'%m-%d-%Y', which works. That's the problem with your first attempt, where you tried to use`%Y-%m-%d`. There is NO month`21`or day`2016`.

Your second attempt is valid but your question makes it appear it doesn't work. You need to be more careful with your testing:

```
params = {event:{start_date:'03-21-2016'}}
DateTime.strptime(params[:event][:start_date], '%m-%d-%Y') # => #<DateTime: 2016-03-21T00:00:00+00:00 ((2457469j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```